# How to avoid double search on std::unordered_map AND avoid calling factory function when not required when implementing a cache

Tags: c++, c++17, unordered-map

I've been implementing a cache based on std::unordered_map. I want to avoid calling the factory function that generates the value if the value is already stored but I also want to avoid running the search on the map twice.

```
#include <unordered_map>

struct Value {
    int x;
    Value & operator=(Value const &) = delete;
};

using Cache = std::unordered_map<int, Value>;

Value make_value(int i){
    // Imagine that this takes a time ok!
    i = i + 1;
    return Value{i};
}

// This has double search
template <typename F>
Value & insert_a(Cache & cache, int key, F factory)
{
    auto i = cache.find(key);
    if(i==cache.end()){
        auto r = cache.try_emplace(key,factory(key));
        return r.first->second;
    }
    return i->second;
}

// This runs the factory even if it is not required
template <typename F>
Value & insert_b(Cache & cache, int key, F factory)
{
    auto r = cache.try_emplace(key,factory(key));
    return r.first->second;
}

int main(){
    std::unordered_map<int,Value> map;

    insert_a(map,10,make_value);

    insert_b(map,10,make_value);

    return 0;

}
```

I have two simplified implementations of *insert* demonstrating how one could build the cache.

The *insert_a* uses find first to detect if the item exists and only if it doesn't calls the factory to get the value. Two searches on the container are performed.

The *insert_b* calls *try_emplace* and just returns the stored value. This is obviously bad because the factory is called even if the value is already there.

It seems I want a middle ground where I pass the factory function directly to try_emplace and internally it is called only if required. Is there a way to simulate this?

This is not a question in general about how to build a cache. I am aware of multi-threading issues, const correctness and mutable keywords. I am specifically asking how to get both

- Single search of the container
- Only call factory if required

Please note that I have deleted the copy assign operator deliberately for the *Value* class. An obvious answer is to insert a default value first and then overwrite it. Not all classes are copy assignable and I want to support those.

There is a sandbox to play with https://godbolt.org/z/Gja3MaGWf

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace ?

Comment: @erenon I'm already using try_emplace. What is the meaning of your suggestion?

Comment: emplace forwards arguments to the constructor of a type. It doesn't forward arguments to an abitrary factory function which is the problem I'm discussing.

Comment: Perhaps store a light-weight proxy object instead of the `Value` objects directly? The proxy object could invoke the factory function to create the actual object if needed (perhaps with the help of [`std::call_once`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once)) and then cache the actual object for proxying the functions to the real object.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing: I meant, if you turn the factory function into a constructor (or wrap `Value` by a type the does that), map::emplace would do exactly what you want, right?

Comment: @erenon The accepted answer covers this in detail but you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a lazy factory. Ie one that only calls the actual factory when needed:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
struct Value {
    int x;
    Value & operator=(Value const &) = delete;
};

using Cache = std::unordered_map<int, Value>;

Value make_value(int i){
    // Imagine that this takes a time ok!
    i = i + 1;
    return Value{i};
}

template <typename F>
Value & insert_b(Cache & cache, int key)
{
    auto r = cache.try_emplace(key,F{key});
    return r.first->second;
}

// call the factory when needed    
struct ValueMaker {
    int value;
    operator Value() {
        std::cout << "called\n";
        return make_value(value);
    }
};

int main(){
    std::unordered_map<int,Value> map;
    insert_b<ValueMaker>(map,10);
    insert_b<ValueMaker>(map,10);
    return 0;

}
```

Output is

```
called
```

because `ValueMaker::operator Value` is only called once when the element is inserted into the map. On the second call, the value maker (which is just a slim wrapper) is not converted to a `Value` because the `key` is already in the map.

I tried to change as little as possible on your code. For your actual code you might want to get rid of the two factories (`make_value` and `ValueMaker`) and use only one. The key point is to pass some light wrapper to `try_emplace` that only triggers the construction of the actual value when it is converted to `Value`.